# How to tweak this eclipse.ini file to improve the performance of eclipse(Helios)?

Tags: eclipse, helios

Here's my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

What all should i add to improve the speed of eclipse to this.I have a 3GB Ram so i am looking forward to increase the memory allocated to eclipse.
Would increasing `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize` do the job?
I have read this [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse#144349)  .But the ini file seems to be a bit different from  mine.I was a bit skeptical that i would corrupt my workspace and other settings so didn't play around with it.

Can someone advise me on what to add and change here so as to improve the performance of eclipse

Comment: You might be looking at the instructions for an older version, at least based on your link. The Helios specific instructions are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659
Also, to increase the amount of memory available to Eclipse, change the -Xmx value from 384m to 1024m, for example.

Comment: @Zsolt,@pdeva:Thanks.I will try it out and let you know

Comment: @Zsolt:I had checked the link for new settings for eclipse Helios.What all should i paste in the .ini file from the settings given in that link.I read through the file settings given there but couldn't make out what all it actually meant.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to ensure that Eclipse is started with a more current JDK. Currently, you only demand that Java version should be at least 1.5. If your Eclipse is really running with JDK 1.5, going to Java7 will give you a way much better performance, and I suspect start-up performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

Give it more memory.
Make it something like -Xmx2g.
This way if eclipse ever needs more memory it will be able to use it, if not then it will keep using the same amount of memory it always does.